# Joining Tables with Criteria

Tags: sql-server, join

How do I create an MSSQL query that joins TableA with TableB using the `ID` field, however I want it to join on `ID` record that has the highest value in the `Number` column?

```
TableA  
ID  
1   
2   
3   
4   

TableB  
ID  Number
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
3   1
3   2
4   1
4   2
4   3
```

I would want this as my output

```
TableJoined
ID Number
1  3
2  1
3  2
4  3
```

Is there a way to use a LEFT JOIN to achieve this or using max()?

Comment: what is your current sql code ?

Comment: Think about what you desire. Why do you need to join at all? TableB has everything you need if you originally intended to use an inner join.

Comment: If you have `5` in the TableA, in the output are you expect `ID: 5  Number: 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query as below:

```
Select a.Id, Number from #a a join
(
    Select top(1) with ties * from #b 
    order by row_number() over(partition by id order by number desc) 
) b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I went with your answer because I didn't run into any issues with aggregates.

Answer (score 3):

Both. Use aggregation on the left join.

```
Select t1.id, max(t2.number)
From table1 t1
Left join table2 t2 on t1.id= t2.id
Group by t1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select A.Id, Max(Number) MaxNo from A 
 join B on A.Id=B.Id
 Group by A.Id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create table #a(
id int
)
go
create table #b(
id          int,
number      int  
)
go

insert into #a values(1),(2),(3),(4)

insert into #b values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)


select #b.id,MAX(number) as maximum 
from #b left outer join #a on #b.id=#a.id
group by #b.id
```